# Unexpected closing bracket with split php code

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm receiving the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /blah/blah/Edit.php on LINE_WITH_COMMENT

for this code inside my `Edit.php` view file.

```
<? $categories = $this->config->loader->getCategories(); 
   foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
   <?  $selected = $this->obj->category==$category ? 'selected' : ''; ?> 
       <option value="<?=$category?>" <?=$selected?>><?=$category?></option>

   <?php } ?>  //ERROR IS HERE
```

But if I change `<?php` to the short open tag `<?`, the error goes away, and my script works as expected.

It works on my server with hostgator with `<?php` but on my local machine it's only working with `<?` and giving the fatal error if I have `<?php`.

From `phpinfo()` on the local machine: PHP Version 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.19.04.1

I've changed `<?php` to `<?` for now, but how can I fix this? I prefer not to use short open tags.

Answer (score 0):

It actually turned out my `short_open_tags` were set to `Off` in my `php.ini`.

So I went to `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/` did `nano php.ini`, found the setting by searching `short_open` and changed `short_open_tags = Off` to `short_open_tags = On`... then I decided to turn it back off because... I've read you're supposed to keep it off. Then I changed my other `<?`s to `<?php`.

The problem was that I WAS using short open tags `<?` for parts of the code, and it was not getting evaluated - rather it was output. And I didn't see it was output because I was looking at the rendered page, rather than the source for the page, and i was only seeing confusing problems in the rendered page

Comment: Yup.  Always use `<?php` and you'll be in good shape.